# Wait checkbox change for dialog confirmation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to stop the change action for a checkbox if I click on 'NO' from a dialog. The dialog shows, but I can not make the (change) of the checkbox to happen after the dialog is closed

I have tried to use Promise or to do all the action in the afterClosed() method of the dialog, but nothing works to make the (change) of the checkbox to happen after the dialog is closed.

```
export class GenericMessageConfirmDialogComponent {

  constructor(public dialogRef:             
MatDialogRef<GenericMessageConfirmDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }

  onYesClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }
```

//HTML

`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.isActive" (change)="onTaskCheckBoxChange(element)" (click)="onTaskCheckBoxClick($event)">`

```
onTaskCheckBoxChange(model: TaskTableEntryModel) {

    console.log("onTaskCheckBoxChange");
    //this always does not wait for the dialog to close
  }

onTaskCheckBoxClick(event: any) {

    let message = "asdhasdlfca asdcasd  asdd";

    var width = 200 + message.length;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GenericMessageConfirmDialogComponent, {
      width: width + 'px',
      data: { msg: message }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

      if (result == true) {
        console.log("yyyyy");
      } else {
        console.log("nnnn");
        event.preventDefault(); //this should stop the change of the checkbox
      }
    });
}
```

Also tried:

```
let message = "asdhasdlfca asdcasd  asdd";

    var width = 200 + message.length;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GenericMessageConfirmDialogComponent, {
      width: width + 'px',
      data: { msg: message }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().toPromise().then(data => {
      console.log("pppppppppppp");
      console.log(data);
    });

    console.log("after promise");
```

Here still I can not make it to wait the promise to finish. The line console.log("after promise"); will happen while the dialog is opened. So I just need to make it act as synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    event.preventDefault(); //this should stop the change of the checkbox
```

This won't work because the anonymous function you are creating here is called asynchronously and won't get called until after the event has already finished.

Why don't you just set the value of element.isActive to be the previous value on the no click.  Something like this assuming element.isActive is a boolean.

```
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

      if (result == true) {
        console.log("yyyyy");
      } else {
        element.isActive = !element.isActive;
        console.log("nnnn");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried also this, but still won't fully fix my problem. My intention was to have the dialog subscribe to act "synchronous", before the (change) will happen.

Comment: On the (change) method, I also put a API call. To partially fix it, I've moved the (change) method content inside the (click) method, although the UI won't act to pretty (the checkbox will change its value while the dialog is opened, since when a dialog is opened, as you said, it is async)

Comment: Why can't you just `event.preventDefault()` in the outer function and set the model to the appropriate value after the dialog closes?  That's the more "angular" way to do it.  You shouldn't block the event for the whole time the dialog is open, that might cause some strange UI behavior

Comment: Yep, that works. I was confused a little because on click you can not see yet the new value of the checkbox, it is available only in the (change) phase. 
Thank you